# Copy data from production DB to Archival DB

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Please suggest how to fix below error.

My .sh file location: `/archiveDB/service_arc.sh` (x.x.x.85 server)

`service_arc.sh` script:

```
 export PGPASSWORD=puser
/appdb/edb/install/9.5AS/bin/psql -h x.x.x.85 -p 5444 -U puser -d pdb -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM service_arc_old ) TO STDOUT;"  | /appdb/edb/9.5as/bin/psql -h x.x.x.92 -p 2442 -U puser -d pdb  -c "COPY service_arc FROM STDIN;"
```

```
nohup ./service_arc.sh > service_arc.log 2>&1 &
tail -f service_arc.log
```

**Error:**

```
nohup: ignoring input
./service_arc.sh: line 2: /appdb/edb/9.5as/bin/psql: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. There is no`/appdb/edb/9.5as/bin/psql` - your path is probably wrong. It certainly doesn't match the call to psql at the start of your command.

Comment: I have uploaded profile in below code. Can you please advise how to set path (password to open file : password) https://easyupload.io/az1dcy

Comment: @NEI If you want to add information, please [edit] your question and copy&paste it there. Did you check that a file `/appdb/edb/9.5as/bin/psql` exists? Please **copy&paste** commands and output instead of retyping.